# How to call server side button event from javascript function in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dopostback

while trying to call a server side button event from javascript function my code looks like this

```
 _doPostBack('CalendarButton','CalendarButton_Click');
```

where **CalendarButton** is my buttonname and 'CalendarButton_Click' is my **CalendarButtonevent**

But this statement is not working. I know there is some minor error but i can't find what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one `_` it has two

```
__doPostBack
```

Comment: I have modified according to your answer but still the server side event has not been called......
  '__doPostBack('CalendarButton','CalendarButton_Click');'

Comment: are there error messages in the console? What is happening in the browser?

Comment: No error messages...............the function doesn't get executed for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to pass in the second argument to `__doPostBack()`. Just `__doPostBack('CalendarButton', '')`.

Alternatively you can call `click()` on the button itself. `document.getElementById("CalendarButton").click();`.

Comment: Open the Script console (F12 in Internet Explorer) and see if your script does not generate an error.

Comment: In __doPostBack, if i write my server side textchanged event then the event is being called but in case of button it doesn't. What is happening??